# How to turn off VS code explorer file selected highlight border?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: This is the blue color border I mean]

I tried bunch of settings, but I can't find how to disable it.

Comment: search the theme colors and customize that color for your theme, other themes, like Light+, don't have that border

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any setting to disable that highlight directly.  You will have to use `workbench.colorCustomizations` in your settings.json.  You should review the `Lists and trees` section of [theme colors: lists and trees](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#lists-and-trees)

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "list.activeSelectionBackground": "#0000",    // note 4 hex characters
    "list.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#0000"
}
```

The fourth hex character in the color setting represents the opacity setting.  So setting it to `0` means that setting has no effect.

Comment: I fixed it using the extension "Customize UI" in VSCode; add the following lines in settings.json:

"customizeUI.stylesheet": {
    ".monaco-list-row.focused": "outline: 0px !important",
},

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using the extension "Customize UI" in VSCode; add the following lines in settings.json:

```
"customizeUI.stylesheet": {
    ".monaco-list-row.focused": "outline: 0px !important",
},
```